# How do I open two/multiple fullscreen views simultaneously in 10.7 Lion?

Tags: macos, fullscreen

When I open two Lion-supported-fullscreen apps in dual-monitor mode, one monitor shows one app while the other monitor shows a "fabric" pattern/texture. The other fullscreen app is available by swipe or Mission Control as another view, but I'd prefer to have the two fullscreen apps up simultaneously (and no cloth pattern texture on the other screen). Is there a way to customize my setup natively or with apps to accommodate?

Moreover, is there a way to disable the second screen's "fabric" pattern/texture altogether (showing the desktop or other apps in that view)?

[image: spotify 1]
[image: spotify 2]
[image: preview 1]
[image: preview 2]

Comment: Related / duplicate [1](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17941/how-do-i-run-an-app-in-full-screen-mode-on-os-x-lion-on-my-second-monitor) [2](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25463/two-full-screen-apps-in-osx-lion-when-using-multiple-monitors) [3](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18679/multiple-monitors-in-lion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. I am hoping Apple will fix this as soon as possible as well.

There's a trick where you can put some app in the fabric space, as documented in [OS X hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110908164921875).

> However, if you utilize the full-screen swipe gesture to move to a separate full screen and pause/stop in the middle with multiple Spaces in view and invoke another application (i.e. via Spotlight), the spawned application can reside in the 'fabric space' or anywhere else. It basically remains attached to that space.

Answer (score -2):

you have to go to system preferences, display settings with both monitors attached.  And you can choose one screen to be a primary with the menu top and bottom, (if that's where you have them).  the second screen, will be secondary, and you can choose a unique photo background for it, as it will have its own preferences open on that screen. if you have a laptop screen open, it will use that as the 2nd monitor as well, if you have one main monitor.  and in expose, you should have the same background picture for each virtual desktop.

Comment: This question is about putting 2 fullscreen applications on different monitors in Lion like you can in Mavericks, and is in no way related to wallpaper/desktop backgrounds.